# how to select multiple nodes with different color in jstree

Tags: jquery, jstree

I want to select nodes with different colors based on their ids

So how we can changed the color of each nodes which selected.

Is it correct ?

```
$("#id a:first").css("background-color", "red");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass id as your id value.
Means if your li id as "node_10" then your have to pass

```
$("#node_10 a:first").css("background-color", "red");
```

You need to define this in .bind method.

```
.bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) 
{
     $("#node_10 a:first").css("background-color", "red");
});
```